# Is Registered I/O still a good choice for WIN32 network applications?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, udp, winsock

My Windows project is to collect application data and forward them on a VXLAN tunnel. I am not a WIN32 programming expert. I see multiple choices to send packets on UDP socket, like send, WSASend, TransmitPackets and Registered I/O. I am puzzled by the differences. Can anyone share some light on which one is best for high throughput applications. Is Registered I/O still a good choice? Seems most RIO post were about 5 to 10 ten years back. Thanks!

Comment: Link where you heard about something named "Registered I/O"?  There are several I/O paradigms in windows, like blocking I/O, overlapped I/O with events, overlapped I/O with completion ports... and none of them use the phrase "registered I/O".

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt! here is link to RIOSendEx: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nc-mswsock-lpfn_riosendex

Comment: RIO is not guaranteed to be available on any given system, so you'd still have to write networking code using the traditional techniques to fall back to.

Comment: Hi Ben, in above link, it says "Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2: This function is supported for Windows Store apps on Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, and later." That's enough for me now.

Comment: That just means the typedefs and prototypes are provided by the Windows SDK for those targets.  It doesn't mean that the `WSAIoctl` call to get the structure full of function pointers will succeed, and when it doesn't, you need a fallback plan.

Comment: Good point. I will test it out. Thanks!

Comment: I found that for receiving UDP packets with recv, WSARecv etc... you will hit a bottleneck pretty quick.

Comment: The biggest problem is transferring the data from kernel to user space. This causes a lot of buffer/pointer verification calls and that really slows down everything. The TCP/IP stack in Windows does perform badly in general when we are talking UDP packets.

Comment: I built an application receiving UDP packets via optical 10G LAN and simply calling recv would slow down the _entire_ Windows OS to the point of being unsuable. It basically behaves as if someone was running a DOS attack. Even the Windows task manager stops responding until I pull the optical LAN cable. (Yes, I did check all the right buttons in the driver such as interrupt moderation etc...)

Comment: So RIO looks like a promising solution, since it preallocates the buffers and reuses them, but it also looks half-baked, poorly documented, microsoft specific only and probably dated - a half-hearted attempt that may or may no longer get much love from microsoft. See here: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/268716/has-winsock-registered-io-performance-degraded-sin.html

Comment: I ended up using WinPCap capturing the entire network traffic and extracting the UDP data from there myself. That gives me pretty good performance.

Like I said, this was for receiving UDP packets.

Comment: @HajoKirchhoff thanks for sharing all the information, very interesting and useful. My situation is different from yours, I don't receive much UDP packets but send a lot, so my bottleneck is Tx side. Compared to send/WSASend/TransmitPackets, RIO did a good job and improved my Tx performance significantly on Windows 2012R2 VMs.

Comment: But the link you shared brought me concern about "RIO performance degraded since 2012?". Did you see RIO performance difference on newer Windows? I will test it on Windows server 2016 and 2019. @HajoKirchhoff

Comment: @mycheese Please keep me/us updated. The WinPCap approach is working for us, but it is a bit clunky and has it's own problems. How many packets per sec are you sending? And are you sending them to different ports or all to the same port? If RIO is working well, then I'd like to keep it in mind.

Comment: @HajoKirchhoff With same application, I do see UDP Tx performance decrease on Windows server 2016 compared to 2012. I don't know why. I have to dig deeper. I am sending about 2Gbps to same remote IP/port.

Comment: 2Gbps. How many (UDP) packets are you sending per second?

Comment: @HajoKirchhoff - Sorry I take my old statement back. **I don't see UDP performance degrade since Windows server 2012.** With Windows server 2012r2/2016/2019, I can get almost line rate of UDP TX on a 2vcpu/1Gbps vNIC, and 4vcpu/4Gbps vNIC. Another issue is, sometimes after system reboot, UDP TX performs very slow (1.2Gbps on 2Gbps interface) up till next reboot. That is on Azure and happened to all different version of Windows Server. Most time is good and I don't know why.

Comment: About packets rate, I don't have a good tool to show it. But here is the calculation: let's take Tx rate 1.9Gbps as example on a 2Gbps / MTU 1500 interface, packet rate is at least 1.9*1024*1024*1024 / (8 * 1500) = 170K pps. And it doubles to about 340K pps on a 4Gbps interface. Is this right?

Comment: 170pps packet rate seems pretty good. Thanks for the update.